# Point to a file in subfolder with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've wanted to move my index.php file from the root to /system/ folder, this is for no reason but giving myself opporunity to learn more about .htaccess, which I am finding very confusing.

How can I achieve this? Currently my code looks as follows

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?query=$1
```

This allows for example mydomain.com/some-url/ to become /index.php?query=some-url for example, this far I'm with it all. But moving the file into System folder and addind /system/ before /index.php does nothing. How does one do this? Thanks!

Comment: Good that you have posted your htaccess file(your efforts) in your question, could you please do add FROM which url TO which url you want to rewrite too in your question for better understanding of question, thank you.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your time and effort to respond to my plead for help!

I'm simply trying to create a simple url rewrite, so normally it would be pointed to my webroot/index.php and now to be webroot/system/index.php without changing the URL from http://localhost/ to http://localhost/system/

I am kind of struggling with how to phrase this in english, if you didn't quite understand please do let me know and I'll try my best to elaborate

Comment: ok so you mean you hit like `http://localhost:80/` and it should be served by `http://localhost:80/system/index.php`, kindly confirm once.

Comment: That's exactly what I want, correct

Answer (score 1):

This could be done with a simple rewriterule. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ system/index.php [L]
```